# High level practice for ignore exception for mongoDB in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I'm using mongoDB to store error logs from my project, but the issues is that sometime mongoDB can not be connected or duplicated value and then throw the error make python process crash.

```
client = MongoClient()
mongodb = client[db]
class CollectionNames:
    Invoke = 'invoke'
md = 'error'
mongodb[CollectionNames.invoke].insert_one(md)
```

I can not write one by one try catch exeption for all pymongo built-in function  `insert_one` or `insert_all`

```
try:
    mongodb[CollectionNames.Invoke].insert_one(md)
except:
    nothing()
```

how can I wrap `insert_one` before pymongo built-in function.

Comment: You wrap it the way you showed. Put that code into a function and call it when you want to insert something.

Comment: How about crafting a script to "write" it one by one programmatically? Seems like the modification to be performed is always the same. (I didn't say this is easy. This is just a possibility.)